# Haskell GTK and Monad Transformers

Tags: haskell, gtk, monads, monad-transformers, gtk2hs

I'm making and application with UI and I need to run code that is in a `StateT` and a `ReaderT` over `IO`, I'm using `Graphics.UI.Gtk` for the UI and I have the following problem:

I need that when a certain button is clicked it calls a function that has signature

```
tryAttack :: Int -> ReaderT Builder (StateT BattleState IO) Bool
```

but in `GTK`, on the `clickedOn` function it takes an `IO ()` argument:

```
onClicked :: ButtonClass b => b -> IO () -> IO (ConnectId b)
```

How can I make "fool" this `clickedOn` function to think that `tryAttack` is `IO ()`.

```
attackButton builder leftTR i = do
    moveButton <- builderGetObject builder castToButton ("move" ++ show i)
    onClicked moveButton $ do
        ok <- tryAttack i
        if ok
            then hideAndShow builder castToTable "fight" "option"
            else return ()
```

---

```
tryAttack :: Int -> ReaderT Builder (StateT BattleState IO) Bool
tryAttack i = return True
```

obviously the `tryAttack` code is temporary.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to unwrap the reader monad and then state monad to get the bool result:

```
(ok,newBattleState) <- runStateT (runReaderT (tryAttack i) builder) battleState
```